# Eric Martin's SimpleModal breaks jquery ui tabs after closing the modal

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, simplemodal

I used [simpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) and jquery-ui tabs for this project. I have a link named "Filter" on the form that will call FilterModal() to display the modal.

```
function FilterModal() {
   $('#divFilterModal').modal();
}
```

Div #divFilterModal is inside _Filter.cshtml.

```
<div">@Html.Partial(MVC.Sample._Filter)</div>
```

Inside **_Filter.cshtml**, I have two link buttons, one is **"Run"** that will execute filter from the selected choices then posting back the result and closes the modal, second is **"Cancel"** that will just close the popup. Also I have used jquery ui Tabs on this control.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FilterModalTabs').tabs();
 });
```

So when I click the Filter link, the modal pops up and the tabs is working well. Every thing is ok if I click "Run" button. But when I click the "Cancel" button, when I open again the modal, the tabs are breaking up. Every time I click to another tab, the previous tab will not deselect/unfocus making more tabs opened.

I check the jquery ui script if it was deleted when the modal was close, but it is still there. Any idea on this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this one. The trick is you should initialize the tab inside onShow. Here's the code.

```
$('#divFilterModal').modal({
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        $('#FilterModalTabs').tabs();
    },
    onClose: function (diag) {
        $.modal.close();
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem and I tried your solution but this does not work. Please see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823767/jquery-ui-tabs-fail-after-hiding-and-reshowing with examples